# How to setup GCP Cloud Function access Firestore both on the same GCP Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Need help I really don't know where to start I created a web app that access data from a Firestore on a GCP Project.

Now I need to use GCP Cloud Functions that connects to Firestore to perform CRUD Functions.

All are on the same GCP Project.

Thanks in advance I really need to know  where to start on Cloud Functions how to define and access via code (Nodejs) the Firestore DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a step by step guide on how to setup Firestore with Cloud Function in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-functions-firestore), but summing it up, it's pretty simple. All you need to do is export the [firestore sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore), initialize the sdk, and use it in your code.

You can also use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) since Cloud Functions is "server side", and this will allow more elevated access to the Firestore from you Cloud Functions.

Comment: This really help me a lot. Thank you so much.